# Can’t install android SDK platforms and SDK tools

Tags: android

Recently I have installed Android Studio 3.0.1 and SDK on my windows 10 computer. But I am encountered with the following problems to start my Project.
When I create my first application the following error message was displayed

**Error: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk Install missing platform(s) and sync project**

I tried to download and install the missing Platform online but after finishing the download and try to install the platform, nothing is changed, rather the download starts again and SDK manager is still empty. Even though the error message says failed to find the path 'android-26', it is already created in the ‘platform’ folder of SDK path with all necessary files.
Another Problem is the SDK manager is empty, the content that is going to be installed appears only when it is connected with Internet and it disappears as soon as I go offline.

*What is the problem?* I have been searching everywhere for answer but with no success. If there is a way I would prefer to download all the necessary files and then install them offline because every time I try to install them online either the speed is very slow or the download interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ways : 

1-check your sdk path.i think your sdk path is invalid

2- clear your sdk and download sdk from this link

 `https://dl2.soft98.ir/mobile/Android.SDK.Release.25.2.5.Win.rar?1519592698` and change your sdk path from android studio. its worked for me

Comment: The SDK path is correct, I already downloaded the above file and placed it in the correct path. I think the problem is not about the path, it is only I can't install plaforms, platform tools, build tools and etc Please I need help.

Comment: maybe your sdk is not complete . my link is complete sdk

Comment: Ok bro, I will download and try that file but my question is, is it compatible with Android  Studio 3.0.1?